# Can we do this in boolean algebra? Drop same terms first, then apply rules?

Tags: boolean-algebra

Given (W+X+Z)(W'X'+Y)(Y+Z), and would like to prove that it is the same as  (W+X+Z)((W'X')+Y). As we can see that the first term,(W+X+Z), is the same, so we can drop it first(correct?)

```
Now we have:Left is (W'X'+Y)(Y+Z) and right is ((W'X')+Y).
Left= (W'X'+Y)(Y+Z)
    = W'X'Y            +  W'X'Z                + Y                +  YZ
    = W'X'Y            +  W'X'Z                + Y                +  YZ 
    = W'X'YZ + W'X'YZ' +  W'X'YZ + W'X'Y'Z     + Y                +  YZ 
    = W'X'YZ + W'X'YZ' +  W'X'YZ + W'X'Y'Z     + WXYZ + W'X'Y Z'  +  YZ 
    = W'X'YZ + W'X'YZ' +  W'X'YZ + W'X'Y'Z     + WXYZ + W'X'Y Z'  +  WXYZ + W'X'YZ
    = W'X'YZ + W'X'YZ' +  W'X'YZ + W'X'Y'Z     + WXYZ + W'X'Y Z'  +  WXYZ + W'X'YZ
    = W'X'YZ + W'X'YZ' +         + W'X'Y'Z     +      +           +  WXYZ +  
    = W'X'YZ + W'X'YZ' +   W'X'Y'Z  +    WXYZ
```

Now right side we have:

```
right= ((W'X')             +Y)
     =  W'X'YZ+ W'X'Y'Z'   +Y
     =  W'X'YZ+ W'X'Y'Z'   +WXYZ +  W'X'YZ'
     =  W'X'YZ+ W'X'Y'Z'   +WXYZ +  W'X'YZ'
```

Now since W'X'Y'Z and W'X'YZ'  are not the same, therefoce  (W+X+Z)(W'X'+Y)(Y+Z) and (W+X+Z)((W'X')+Y) are the the same ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that (A)(AB) = (A)(B), but this does not imply that you can drop the first part and that AB = B. In other words, a difference in the second part might be masked by changes in the first part that are dependent on the same variables.

So in the general case, dropping identical terms is not allowed.

In this particular case, a counterexample exists for W=X=Y=Z=0:

```
(W+X+Z)(W'X'+Y)(Y+Z) = 0 and (W+X+Z)((W'X')+Y) = 0, but 
       (W'X'+Y)(Y+Z) = 0 and        ((W'X')+Y) = 1
```